# How to get rid of syntax error while setting up selenium and importing webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, import, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

[selenium setup][1]

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

I have tried to replace the \ with \ or with / and I've tried to put an r before "C.. but all these things didn't work. I even uninstalled and tried again but didn't work.

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_driver_path = "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)
driver.get("https://instagram.com")
driver.close()
```

Comment: Try two slashes.. "c:\\users..."  etc... Seems python thinks "\u" is for unicode strings.

Comment: You can paste the image directly in Stackoverflow's editor, which would make it appear in the answer directly (no link). I bet more people would answer you :).